# I want to create a countour map from x, y and z and clip the data with the shapefile using ggplot

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, shapefile

I have a data set with Eastings, Northings and Age. I want to plot the age for my data set. 
The dataset is upload in the following loation:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmtxluhwuupb9iv/age%20at%202100.csv

The code I used to create the simple graph and contour is as follows:

```
age2100 <- read.csv("age at 2100.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
p <- ggplot(age2100, aes(x=Eastings, y=Northings, colour=("Age")))+geom_point()
p+geom_density2d()
```

The output I got is as follows:

I couldn't upload the image so please find the image at the following dropbox location :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5k5gefqi7wz6v36/age.png

Now, I want to add a shapefile on the background and clip the contour lines to the shapefile.

The desired output is as follows:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqhx2t8cqqozwbt/7Q10%20flow%20dye%20from%20P%20and%20S.JPG

How do I proceed from figure 1 to desired output ? If anyone could give me suggestions, that would be great.

Thank you so much.

Jdbaba

Comment: The desired output is found on this link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqhx2t8cqqozwbt/7Q10%20flow%20dye%20from%20P%20and%20S.JPG

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should modify your original question to add additional information rather than include it in a comment. That keeps the questions self-contained.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your suggestion. I have edited my original post now.

Comment: Have you looked at the `ggmap` vignette?

Comment: Thank Ari. B. Friedman for your suggestion. But I haven't looked at ggmap vignette. I don't know how to use ggmap vignette.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- Which document are you referring to? `vignette(package="ggmap")` turns up no 'hits'...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Oops.  He'd sent me a PDF that was helpful, and I assumed it was the vignette.  Can't find it now, but there are other resources out there for `ggmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. If Google Maps is ok, then use `ggmap`.
2. If it has to be your shapefile, look at `fortify` in `ggplot`, which has methods for `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`s.